# Program not returning a String

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, return

Method:

```java
public String getRowsOf3Stars (int rows)
```

Description:

> Compulsory Exercise 2) Complete the getRowsOf3Stars method which is
>   passed an int(rows) as a parameter. The method returns a String
>   containing that number of 3-stars rows.

For example,

```java
getRowsOf3Stars(2)  // returns “***\n***\n”
```

If rows is less than 1, returns an empty String.
An example:

```java
getRowsOf3Stars(2)  // should return "***\n***\n"
```

What I wrote:

```java
public String getRowsOf3Stars (int rows) {
    String getRowsOf3Stars="***\n";
    if (rows<1){
        String none="";
        return none;
    }
    else{
        for(int starRows=1;starRows<rows;starRows++){
            return getRowsOf3Stars;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I recieve on CodeWrite:

```java
private String getRowsOf3Stars(int rows) throws Exception {
    >> This method must return a result of type String
```

Can someone please explain why my program isn't returning a String?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
for(int starRows=1;starRows<rows;starRows++){

return getRowsOf3Stars(starRows); //  your code here don't return any thing here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `return "";` as last line of your method to get rid of the error. It's complaining because there is a chance your current lines where you're returning might never be called due to the conditions you have.

If for example you provide an argument rows = 1, the return will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler would make sure that there is a string return from the method.
Now see the code,

1)          `if(rows<1)`

then only if will work and return a string.

2)But       `if (rows>=1)`

then it will go to the for loop, and the compiler cannot determine at the compile time that the for loop will execute or not, as this is a runtime mechanism.So its not sure for the compiler that for loop will execute or not.
And if for loop doesn't execute, your method will not return anything.

Now since compiler has to make it sure, that there should be a string return, it is showing that error.

So what you can do is that, in the else clause after for loop you can return a default string as `return "";` or as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue of not returning a string, I don't see a reason for the internal loop as you are issuing a return inside the loop.  I think this would accomplish what you want:

```
public String getRowsOf3Stars (int rows) {
String ROWOF3STARS = "***\n";
String returnString = "";

if (rows > 0){

    for(int starRows=1;starRows<rows;starRows++){
        returnString += ROWOF3STARS;
    }
}
return returnString;
}
```

Hope this helps.